# How do I make pairs of array values?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Consider the following array as input:

```
$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

I'm looking for a way to make loop though this array, writing down every possible pair of two values. In this example: AB AC AD BC BD CD. Please not that BA doesn't count as a pair, since AB is already mentioned:

```
$output = array(
  'A' => 'B',
  'A' => 'C',
  'A' => 'D',
  'B' => 'C',
  'B' => 'D'
);
```

Any input on how to get this started is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can have more than 1 array element with the same key 'A'.

Comment: What you need is a different data structure. Array doesn't fit your purpose.

Comment: An array with numeric indexes could fit: `array('AB', 'AC', ...)`.

Comment: are: C => D, A => A, B => B ... possible outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output=array();
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($input);$i++) {
  $k=$input[$i];
  for ($j=$i+1;$j<sizeof($input);$j++) {
    $v=$input[$j];
    $output[]=array($k=>$v);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

As of your comment, the restructured output

```
$output=array();
//See below
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($input);$i++) {
  $k=$input[$i];
  $v=array();
  for ($j=$i+1;$j<sizeof($input);$j++) {
    $v[]=$input[$j];
  }
  $output[]=array($k=>$v);
}
```

This will give you 'D'=>Array() as a last row, if you don't want hti you have to change

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($input);$i++) {
```

to

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($input)-1;$i++) {
```

Comment: This works great; but is it possible to rebuild after Gauravs sample output? $output = array('A' => array('B','C','D'), 'B' => arrat('C','D')); That's probably much cleaner that what I came up with :)

Comment: I had to change $output[]=array($k=>$v); into $output[$k]=$v; to get the output as I wanted it, but thanks! You have been of great help :)

Comment: @Reveller Ah, I see what you mean. I misunderstood (= lazy read) the desired structure.

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe;

```
$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$input_copy = $input;
$output = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($input as $val) {
    $j = 0;
    foreach($input_copy as $cval) {
        if($j < $i) break;
        $output[] = array($val => $cval);
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}

$output = array(
    0 => array('A' => 'A'),
    1 => array('A' => 'B'),
    2 => array('A' => 'C'),
    ...
);
```

Note that your output array is impossible, as the key is overwritten each time

Comment: c'mon, with a little tweak of yourself this could work. It's not a script-request site, but a question and answer... check out the edit

Comment: @giorgio - the comment is not mine. I have upvoted his reply...it was appreciated even with the misinterpretation :)

Comment: for your honesty one minor upgrade for free ;) `if($j <= $i) break;` is now `if($j <= $i) break;` (otherwise the pair 'A' => 'A' would not show)

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible in PHP, as PHP array can have only unique keys.

You can get output as

```
$output = array(
  'A' => array('B','C','D'),
  'B' => array('C','D')
);

$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
foreach($input as $key => $value){
   $tempKey = $key;
   for($key +1 ; $key < count($input) ; $key++){
      $result[$tempKey][] = $input[$key];
   }
}
```

Comment: That's true. This would be a far better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic method:

```
function combine($inputArray, &$outputArray, $index, $combLen) {
        global $outstr;
        for ($i = $index; $i < count($inputArray); $i++) {
                $outstr.=$inputArray[$i];
                if(strlen($outstr) == $combLen) {
                        $outputArray[]= $outstr;
                }
                combine($inputArray, $outputArray, $i + 1, $combLen);
                $outstr = substr($outstr, 0, strlen($outstr)-1);
        }
}
```

[**See it on ideone**](http://ideone.com/hvoDU)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to work with pairs as arrays

```
$pairs = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    foreach(array_slice($a, $k + 1) as $k2 => $v2) {
        $pairs[] = [$v, $v2];
    }
}
```