# how to make pairs of array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array something like that:

```
array('A','B','C','D','E');
```

and I want to make pairs of each value like that :

```
  A, AB, ABC, ABCD, ABCDE
  B, BC, BCD, BCDE
  C, CD, CDE
  D, DE
  E
```

as an `Array` (ALL PAIRS SHOULD BE IN A SAME ARRAY).

And I have followed this Question:

[How do I make pairs of array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176291/how-do-i-make-pairs-of-array-values)

But i'm not able to do that.

Please Help

Comment: hello walter white, this is childs play to you :) , wheres your attempt?

Comment: So two nested loops, should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Ghost i'm not afraid of real Ghost but this childs play already took my 2 hrs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each of your inputs, loop between it and the end of the input array. For each result, add the range between the present and end inputs to your result.

```
$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');

$output = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
    $row = array($input[$i]);
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($input); $j++) {
        $row[] = implode('', range($input[$i], $input[$j]));
    }

    $output[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: It is not allowing me to accept your answer, but i will. and thanks for your precious time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work You need to wait 15 minutes before accepting an answer. Gives everyone else a chance to respond, possibly with something better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array('A','B','C','D','E');
$chars = count($data);

$combinations = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $startChar) {
    $length = 0;
    while ($length < $chars - $key) {
        $combinations[] = implode(array_slice($data, $key, ++$length));
    }
}
var_dump($combinations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the format output:

```
$letters = array('A','B','C','D','E');
$result = array();
$x = 0;
while(count($letters) > 0) {
    $l = array_shift($letters);
    $result[$x][] = $l;
    foreach($letters as $k => $letter){
        $result[$x][] = $l . implode(array_slice($letters, 0, $k+1));
    }
    $result[$x] = implode(', ', $result[$x]);
    $x++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. and it was a childs play ;)